# Nested Repeater - Child Repeater Price Add on Checkbox click into the Parent Repeater Price

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I've Nested Repeaters the parent repeater have the Price, Name, Description and the child repeater have also the same thing but with different values, I'm a bit confused about how can I add Child Repeater Price of any one of the Child Repeater Item into the Price of Parent Repeater on a client side.

I want to achieve it like when I click on the Checkbox checkbox text should change to Added and the Price should update.

UPDATE

My Code that works:

```
<asp:Repeater
    ID="Repeater3"
    runat="server"
    OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="card border-success mb-3">
            <div class="card-header bg-success text-white h4">
                <%# Eval("PName") %>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <%# Eval("PDescription") %>
                <div id="ChildRepeater" runat="server">

                    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="card border-danger my-3">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h4><%# Eval("PName") %></h4>
                                    <h6><asp:Label ID="lblChildPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PRate") %>'></asp:Label></h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-footer">
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAdd" Text="Add" OnCheckedChanged="chkbxAdd_CheckedChanged" runat="server" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                <h2><asp:Label ID="lblParentPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PRate") %>'></asp:Label></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The Code behind:

```
protected void chkbxAdd_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
            RepeaterItem rtpritem = (RepeaterItem)chk.NamingContainer;
            Label lblPlanPrice = (Label)rtpritem.FindControl("lblChildPrice");
            Repeater rptr = (Repeater)chk.NamingContainer.Parent;
            Label lblParentPlanPrice = (Label)rptr.NamingContainer.FindControl("lblParentPrice");

            lblParentPlanPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(double.Parse(lblParentPlanPrice.Text) + double.Parse(lblPlanPrice.Text));

        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate more? What must happen if you click `chkAdd`? I think you want the value of `PRate` to go in the parent Repeater. But where?

Comment: I have achieved now, when I click on the CheckBox that adds up in the Price of the Parent Repeater.

Now whenever I clicked on the checkbox the page postback which is not the good way, I have tried this through updatepanel but when I pass the ControlID to the Triggers it says `A control with ID 'chkbxAdd' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.` What would be the solution of getting the ID of Checkbox.

Comment: I have used a seperate UpdatePanel inside the repeater and now everything is working fine, another issue arise is that when I check and uncheck it should come to it's own price.